What are these extra wires on power lines?
The other day I was having a walk outside on a rural road and noticed something odd about the nearby power lines:

What are these extra wires doing there?
Context: Location - Europe, Latvia. This is a 240V 3-phase power line, coming from the nearest high-voltage transformer a few km away. Not all of the poles had these - I'd say about one in 3-5 poles had the extra wires up there, but they weren't evenly spaced. These extra wires don't seem to be connected anywhere - they just run from the wires to the ceramic insulators and that's that. There were always 4 of them - one for each wire.
Updated: Oh, I completely forgot about this question. :) I inspected the poles some more and realized that there were only a few of them that had this arrangement and they were nearby buildings. After that the power line that disappeared over the next hill didn't have any. So this supports the idea that they are historical connection points.

Maybe they are there just in case they are needed for making a connection. You should have photographed a pole that didn't have them and, used a better contrast.

@Andyaka - Ahh, sorry. It was getting dark and I only had my cell phone. I assumed this would be well known, so didn't worry too much about picture quality. I can snap better pictures next time I'm there. As for regular poles - they're just... regular poles. Instead of 8 insulators (like in the picture) they have only 4 that support the wires.  As for contact places - that was my first thought too, but there were too many of them (one every few poles), and in the middle of nowhere - just pastures all around, nothing that could potentially need a connection.

On such a mains line they're probably there just to facilitate connecting future customers. Note the extra set of insulators that these are connected to. You could probably look at how a house etc. in the area is connected.

Difficult to tell from the angle, but phase swap in order to balance the inductance to be near equal for all phases is a thing, at least for high voltage overhead lines.

@againstverylongusernames - Well, I can't rule it out... but I would find it very odd. Everyone who needs power there already has power. New connections are, like, super rare. You probably get one per decade or so. Easier and cheaper to just add these things when needed, not bolt them onto every other pole. Especially when most of these poles are literally on the same property. And it's not like they would be ancient either - these wooden poles get replaced every decade or two.

@winny - Nice guess, but the load-bearing wires themselves just continue straight through. These small wires literally branch off of them - 40cm to nowhere.

Oh, then just termination for the pole and porcelain insulators.

Your edit seems to resolve the question -- consider adding it as a self-answer instead :)
